# How get enum from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, enums

I've got a table with usernames, password and user role

Got a switch case with the condition being role_ID from UserRole Table which changes roleType enum accordingly.

I'm struggling with accessing this enum from the main menu form.

if RoleTypes is frmLogin.RoleTypes.Doctor

then the relevant buttons are visible.

Thats whats I'm trying to do.

This is where I'm at.

**Login Screen**

```
   private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    public enum RoleTypes
    {

        practiceManager,
        doctor,
        receptionist
    }


            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename....)

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @username and Password = @password", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtBoxUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtBoxPassword.Text);

            conn.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(ds);

            conn.Close();

            bool loginSuccess = (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1);

            if (loginSuccess)
            {

                    switch (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Role_ID"])
                    {

                        case 1:
                            {
                                RoleTypes roleType = RoleTypes.practiceManager;
                                Console.WriteLine("Role type changed to " + roleType);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            {
                                RoleTypes roleType = RoleTypes.doctor;
                                Console.WriteLine("Role type changed to " + roleType);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            {
                                RoleTypes roleType = RoleTypes.receptionist;
                                Console.WriteLine("Role type changed to " + roleType);
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;

                    }
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Logged in.");
                FrmMenu menu = new FrmMenu();
                menu.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);
                Console.WriteLine("Not logged in");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Main Menu**

```
 private void FrmPatients_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmLogin.RoleTypes roleType = new FrmLogin.RoleTypes();

        if (roleType == FrmLogin.RoleTypes.doctor)
        {
            this.btnNewPatient.Visible = false;
        }

     }
```

I know I'm creating a new instance of RoleTypes but how do I reference the existing instance?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How come in your code you don't even show your `RoleTypes` enum? It would be awesome if you provided a [mcve].

Comment: Ah, apologies! I took it out thinking it was unnecessary. It is in now, Can you help?

Comment: Can you please read [mcve] and make sure you have it sorted in your question? As it is I can't begin to even think about trying to run your code as it is not copy, paste and runnable. Your job is to make it easy for us to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Roles.Role == Roles.RoleType.doctor)
//do something
```

Make RoleType as static (you may create Roles class and put enum in it) - if you would do this like that, you can change it's state as in example. You can also use Session variables, if you are working in web app.

```
static class Roles 
{
public RoleType Role;
public enum RoleType 
{
//your role types
}
}

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
switch(i)
{
case 1: { Roles.RoleType = Roles.RoleType.practiceManager; break; }
//rest of cases...
}
}
```

Comment: - I can't set the enum to static and then in btnLogin_Click role.RoleTypes says it inaccessible?